# .NET MAUI Essentials Authenticator error in UWP missing AppManifest.xml

Tags: .net, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.essentials, maui

i'm trying to implement authentication with Essentials API in a .NET MAUI project

```
  async Task OnAuthenticate(string scheme)
    {
        try
        {
            WebAuthenticatorResult r = null;

            if (scheme.Equals("Apple")
                && DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS
                && DeviceInfo.Version.Major >= 13)
            {
                // Make sure to enable Apple Sign In in both the
                // entitlements and the provisioning profile.
                var options = new AppleSignInAuthenticator.Options
                {
                    IncludeEmailScope = true,
                    IncludeFullNameScope = true,
                };
                r = await AppleSignInAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(options);
            }
            else
            {
                var authUrl = new Uri(authenticationUrl + scheme);
                var callbackUrl = new Uri("xamarinessentials://");

                r = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(authUrl, callbackUrl);
            }

            AuthToken = string.Empty;
            if (r.Properties.TryGetValue("name", out var name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                AuthToken += $"Name: {name}{Environment.NewLine}";
            if (r.Properties.TryGetValue("email", out var email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                AuthToken += $"Email: {email}{Environment.NewLine}";
            AuthToken += r?.AccessToken ?? r?.IdToken;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Login canceled.");

            AuthToken = string.Empty;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed: {ex.Message}");

            AuthToken = string.Empty;
        }
```

When call WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync it return the error

Could not find file 'C:\Windows\system32\AppxManifest.xml'.

Someone already implemented authentication in MAUI running on Windows 11?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? getting same error on win 11 ( did not try on win 10)

Comment: Same problem on win 11.

Comment: Same here, also Windows 11

Comment: Looks like it's not unique to Windows 11 since I'm having the same issue on Windows 10. Any solution to this yet?